# Data binding with native HTML in XML not working

Tags: sapui5

I have a master.view.xml which has a list which is loading dynamically from a json file and the content is displayed in CustomListItem. Everything works fine until I replace

```
 <Label text="{ID}"/>
```

with

```
 <html:p>id: {ID}</html:p>
```

The error I get is

Uncaught Error: Neither view name/content nor an XML node is given. One of them is required.

I have no idea what is the problem.

This is my master.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="sap.ui.demo.poa.view.Master"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" >
<Page
    id="page"
    title="Demo App"
    class="myBackgroundStyle"
    enableScrolling="true">
    <subHeader>
        <Bar
            id="searchBar">
            <contentMiddle>
                <SearchField
                    id="searchField"
                    showRefreshButton="{device>/isNoTouch}"
                    search="handleSearch"
                    tooltip="{i18n>masterSearchTooltip}"
                    width="100%" >
                </SearchField>
            </contentMiddle>
        </Bar>
    </subHeader>
    <footer>
        <Toolbar>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://synchronize"
                                    press="onCall" />
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://filter"
                                    press="onStdDialogPress" />
            <Select
                                    icon="sap-icon://vertical-grip"
                type="IconOnly"
                autoAdjustWidth="true">

                <core:Item text="Exit" />

                            </Select>
        </Toolbar>
    </footer>
    <content>

   <List
     id="list"
     backgroundDesign="Transparent"
     items="{/PurchaseOrderCollection}">
    <items>
    <CustomListItem
            press="handleListItemPress"
            title="{ID}"
            >
        <content>
               <Label text="{ID}"/> //Problem Here
            </content>  
    </CustomListItem>
  </items>  
</List>    
    </content>
</Page>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `content` aggregation of a `CustomListItem` only accepts controls of type `sap.ui.core.Control` (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.CustomListItem.html#constructor)

If you need to add custom HTML, consider either using a JS view ([see this example using HTML in an CustomListItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/4f7d43c459844bb7b5b5771dbec22126.html)) since XML views are not supported this way:

> This approach only works when you use JavaScript for the UI. When
>   using a declarative model, such as XML Views, use an on-the-fly
>   control, see [Developing UI5 Controls in JavaScript](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/guide/91f1703b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)